# How can I dock a protein to a nucleic acid?

Tags: proteins, software-recommendation, rna, docking

I have a protein of interest and I would like to now how it interacts with RNA. I have structures of both molecules.

What tool can I use?

Comment: You mean a specific RNA molecule, right? Not any RNA in general?

Comment: Autodock Vina is a common tool for ligand binding studies, if the stretch of RNA isn't too large I suspect it may work with Vina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant but you can take a look at [NPDock](http://genesilico.pl/NPDock) (disclaimer we wrote that tool). If you have a structure of your protein of interest, you can dock it to the structure of your DNA/RNA of interest. Mind that this is a rigid body docking which means that the structure will not change upon binding.